# What should be done when there are joint winners?

Tags: discussion, code-golf, scoring, accepted-answer

On the question [How long is my number: Restricted Version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/121566/how-long-is-my-number-restricted-version), there are multiple answers which are 1 byte long? How should judge which answer to give the green check to?

Comment: @programmer5000 Creative? Coolest? You know how PPCG folks like objectivity :P

Comment: Regardless of the dupe vote, no one forces you to accept any answer. *Especially* if there are trivial 1-byte answers, it might be a good idea to forgo the checkmark completely because it would just pin a boring effortless answer to the top.